# Apache htaccess load file from one directory or another

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

My goal is to simply have Apache rewrite the URL a second time if the requested file isn't found in the first directory.

Right now I have the following Apache rewrite which works great...

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]*/scripts(.+) scripts$1
```

This makes all JavaScript file requests for all domains access files at the following directory...

> www/scripts/

---

My directory/file structure...

> www/
>
> www/scripts/
>
> www/www.example.com/
>
> www/www.example.com/scripts/

What I need to do is *IF* the requested file is not in this directory...

> www/www.example.com/scripts/

...to then have Apache look in this directory...

> www/scripts/

---

This is for **localhost** local development so the request URL will look something like...

> http:// localhost/www.example.com/scripts/index.js

---

Here is an example of something I've been tinkering with...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)\/scripts\/\.(js)$
RewriteCond ^[^/]*scripts$2 -f
RewriteRule ^[^/]*/scripts(.+) scripts$2[L]
```

Comment: Is there a problem with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)\/scripts\/\.(js)$` seems like that would be looking for */scripts/.js - not with anything in the filename?

Comment: @mikevoermans I'm only good enough to *maybe* accidentally stumble on to the answer after a week of non-stop tinkering; your snippet looks much more on-target though, thank you!

Comment: This wasn't intended to be an answer, sorry, haven't tested anything, just thinking your regex was off there. It was a copy from the code you've been tinkering with

Answer (score 1):

Just to hopefully put you closer to a solution. Here is my untested idea:

```
# check if we're looking for a script in that directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} www\/www\.example\.com\/scripts\/(.*)\.js$

# check if that file DOESN'T exist
RewriteCond www\/www\.example\.com\/scripts\/%1\.js !-f

# it doesn't exist - so try to rewrite that file to www/scripts
RewriteRule www\/www\.example\.com\/scripts\/(.+)\.js$ www/scripts/$1.js
```

Good luck